How is it possible that my level in chess.com is 1500 with and without sacrificing queen in the first 3 moves?
I have two phones and two different accounts on chess.com. In the first one I always play naturally and my level is around 1500. But in the second phone I always sacrifice the queen in the first 3 moves (getting the pawns on f7, f2 etc.) and then i play naturally. What is unexplainable is that even in the second phone my level is around 1500. It looks like that if I don't sac my queen I meet strong players, but if I sac her, I meet weak players.
An explanation?

I don’t think the style of play impacts future opponents. It’s based on results. And the change in rating is based on the delta. So there may well be some convergence

I do suggest that you give more data about the numbers of games, trajectories of results etc

Maybe sacking the queen on move 3 is underrated? You could be on the verge of revolutionizing opening theory.

Perhaps they think your Hikaru or some GM streamer. It's an intimidation tactic.
